# Keep array data on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to keep values in my array on different pages (`Wordpress`), I'm trying do this via global array but it doesn't seem to work. On "page-1" I am filling the array with data, the same script is loading when I click "page-2". I would be grateful if you point how to fix my problem.

```
     var myArray = new Array();

       // Here is issue my myArray with data becomes empty after second load
        myArray = {
            tablica: []
        };


        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     // need my array over here

        });
```

Comment: share your whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your app is a spa, a new html page is loaded on navigation. Therefore your JS is re initialise. Global variable does not persist on navigation.

Use local storage, session storage or a server side solution.

Comment: thanks, i used local storage everything is working :)

Answer (score 1):

It will again reinitialize on next page. You can use local storage for get value from first page to another page.

Comment: Thank that was exactly what i was looking for :)